# VM loses LAN Connection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-sbs-2011

I've got an SBS 2011 with Hyper-V. It has 1 Server 2008 VM as Terminalserver on it. When someone starts a Web Browser or opens a link from an e-mail. All users lose connection to the VM. It doesn't crashes, it only loses connection.
When I connect through Hyper-V Manager, it takes a long time to connect.
Any ideas ?

Host:
SBS 2011
32 GB RAM
Xeon E31270
RAID 1 1TB

VM:
Server 2008

Comment: Loss permanent? Check driver, MAC address conflict, Switch? You talk nice about your host, but you totally ignore... the network. Also, the Raid must be EXTREMELY slow. Like super slow. Can it be the VM is jus totally voerlaoded? A terminal server of 32gb is "challenging" (not to say my workstation has more) and you are adding to that a Raid 1 that is 1000 times slower than a single SSD.Oh, and you know that pretending to have a military title... well, hero.

Comment: Today, it took 40 mins to come back. The VM has 4 cores and 16 GB RAM. And this doesn't get used at all.

Comment: Still no word about disc. Any time somemone runs virtualization and has no performance numbers for disc, that is where i look first.

Comment: Windows SBS 2012 R2? There's no such thing. You have Windows SBS 2011 in your tags. So which is it? What OS is running on the Hyper-V host and which OS is running on the VM?

Comment: thanks, I have literally no experience in the server area. lol

Comment: So maybe you shouldn't be running the Hyper-V Role on SBS 2011. - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/05/18/small-business-server-2011-and-server-virtualization-itcamp-hyperv-sbs2011/